# Exit from anonymous function. jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem. I have following code in anonymous function:

```
        ...
        if (fillActyalizerForm(jQuery(this).attr('account_id'), jQuery(this).attr('currency_id')) == false) {
            return false;
        }
        jQuery("#actyalizer").slideToggle("slow");
        ...
```

THe problem is even if I return false, element slides down.

```
function fillActyalizerForm(account_id, currency_id) {
    formValues = {};
        jQuery.ajax({
            async: false,
            type: 'POST',
            url: "..",
            data: "{'accountId':" + account_id + ",'currencyId':" + currency_id + "}",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                if (data && data.hasOwnProperty("d")) {
                    data = data.d;
                }
                if (!data.Error) {
                    formValues = data;
                    delete formValues.Error;
                } else {
                    alert('<%=Resources.app.Actyalizer_AcLoadFail %>');
                    return false;
                }
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert('<%=Resources.app.Actyalizer_AcLoadFail %>');
                return false;
            }
        });
```

So I am successfully get alert message, but it still slides down the elemtn.

Comment: are you sure it is getting to the return?

Comment: To expand on what @mindandmedia said, check for errors raised by the `fillActyalizerForm` function in your console.

Comment: @mindandmedia,@Rory McCrossan how to make sub-function return false? I'v tried try-catch, but it is failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `fillActyalizerForm` function executes the asynchronous `.ajax` method and then returns without specifying a return value (the default return value is then false).

I think you have two choices:

1. Move the `jQuery("#actyalizer").slideToggle("slow");` into the `success` function.
2. Do a synchronous ajax request.

I would recommend option one.
This can be achieved by passing your function as a parameter to `fillActyalizerForm` or physically move the code.

Comment: i think ill wull use second option

Comment: @JakeFisher, be aware of the disadvantages when using synchronous AJAX calls, it blocks the UI thread!  Research it and make sure that is what you really want.

Comment: Fourie yes you was right about first option. This was more preferrable.